# TensorBook: can't enter Ubuntu desktop

Tags: boot, 18.04, recovery-mode

I have removed Nvidia drivers using `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*` and now I can’t enter desktop, I also get `"A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up(time/no limit)"`, someone can help me without re-install Ubuntu? Thanks.

Comment: You may have blacklisted `nouveau` or the open-source driver for nvidia video cards; you should remove this blacklist (it's common on blogs to do this to force systems to use the nvidia drivers which you've now removed)